# how to have hard keypad on Android Phone?

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-layout, hal

for key-code of Hard-keyboard, HAL is there to bind their controls.

now, the problem is between Application level and HAL. how they both will communicate to each other? 
how the controls of signal takes places from one key presses to its visibility at application side?

I know, android 2.3 onward we got USB access to external keyboard. my ultimate question is how that external keyboard works by just plugging in? wants to know if there are some library/framework for this kind,

Comment: you should look at the documentation for this at https://source.android.com/devices/input/index.html

Comment: Thank You. I have been there once, but found something helpful this time.